# Mathematical expression of the number of names fulfilling the condition

Tags: regular-expressions

I have an example where a total of 2200 names are entered.

1. Each name has an assigned percentage value from 0% to 100%.
2. The total number of names with a value above 88% is 459.

I need to formulate this in a mathematical way in a formula that will point out that it is precisely the 459 names which are those we look for.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Your question will be better appreciated if you show that you have made an effort.

Comment: It would also help if you specify why you need this. Is it just a mathematical notation, or do you want to implement it in some software?

Comment: In the spirit of what Andrei said, do you care at all about the 1741 names whose percentage is 88 or less?  What did you have in mind when you tagged your question with "regular expressions?"

Comment: I just want to have the mathematical expression for my thesis. Please find the file under the following [link](https://goo.gl/q6MRRn)

Comment: Something along the lines of "$W$ is a set of words, $I$ is the interval of the real numbers from $0$ to $100$ and $f : W \to I$ is a function that assigns a percentage to all elements of $W$. Let $H = \{w \in W \mid f(w) > 80\}$"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following expressions:
$$A=\{(x_i,y_i),i=\overline{1,2200},0\le y\le100\}\\|A|=2200\\B=\{(x_i,y_i)\in A,y_i\gt88\}\\B\subset A\\|B|=459$$
You might be able to skip some of the lines. An [alternative notation](https://www.rapidtables.com/math/symbols/Set_Symbols.html) for cardinality is "$\#$".